# CustomErrroHandler not handling the custom exception thrown in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have running Angular 12 application and I want to achieve a behavior to create custom ErrorHandler to handle errors globally.

Whenever I receive Error notification from backend, I subscribe it in the ToolService using this.notificationService.registerToServerCalls(......) . From here I throw the CustomException which should go to the CustomErrorHandler to handle the error. **But, once the CustomException is thrown, the code is not going to the CustomErrorHandler**

**tool.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ToolService {
constructor(
        private notificationService: NotificationService,
        @Inject(ErrorHandler) private errorHandler: CustomErrorHandler) {
        this.errorHandler.onUnhandledException$.subscribe({
            next: (error: ErrorDetail[]) => {
                this.dialogService.open(error);
            }
        });
    }


    this.notificationRService.registerToServerCalls<ErrorDetail[]>('Error', (errorDetail: ErrorDetail[]) => {
                this.onError.next(errorDetail);
                throw new CustomException(errorDetail);
            });
```

**notification.service.ts**

```
public registerToServerCalls<T>(clientMethod: string, callback: (data: T) => void): void {
        this.hubConnection.on(clientMethod, callback);
    }
```

**custom-exception.model.ts**

```
export class CustomException extends Error {
    error: ErrorDetail[];

    constructor(error?: ErrorDetail[]) {
        super();
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

**custom-error-handler.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  private onUnhandledException = new Subject();
  onUnhandledException$ = this.onUnhandledException.asObservable();
  isErrorHandled = false;

  /**
   * Override the base class error handler to handle the error.
   */
  handleError(errorObj) {
    if (this.isErrorHandled) {
      return;
    }
    
    errorObj = errorObj.rejection ? errorObj.rejection : errorObj; // .rejection is required in case of promise rejections.
    let errorDetails: ErrorDetail[];
    
    errorDetails = errorObj.error;

    this.onUnhandledException.next(errorDetails);
    this.isErrorHandled = true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you explicit added your CustomErrorHandler to be the default error handler in your app? Check you app.module.ts , in the providers attribute to have something like this  { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: CustomErrorHandler }

Comment: Yes I have added this { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: CustomErrorHandler in my app.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple explanation for this, though I am not sure why it happens. I had somewhat the same problem recently

The problem is that Angular uses a different instance of `CustomErrorHandler` than the one you inject into your service.

This might be solved by using the following on your errorhandler and services but I highly doubt if that works.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

In my case I used a second service. Something like this:

```
export class ErrorMessageService {
    private onUnhandledException = new Subject();
    onUnhandledException$ = this.onUnhandledException.asObservable();

    setMessage(message: string){
        onUnhandledException.next(message);
    }
}

export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private errorMessageService: ErrorMessageService)

    handleError(errorObj) {
        this.errorMessageService.setMessage(...)
        ...
        ...
    }
}

export class ToolService {
    constructor(
        private notificationService: NotificationService,
        private errorMessageService: ErrorMessageService) 
    {
        this.errorMessageService.onUnhandledException$.subscribe({
        next: (error: ErrorDetail[]) => {
            this.dialogService.open(error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can merge the ErrorMessageService and the Toolservice and inject the toolservice in your errorhandler.